# Megilah or Havdalah, which is done first? Why?

Tags: purim, motzei-shabbos, havdalah, halacha

When *Megilah* reading is *Motza'ei Shabbos* (Saturday Night) what is said first, *Havdalah* or *Megilah* and why?

Comment: Tadir v'sheaynoi tadir, tadir koidem?

Comment: Thats my question is it true or do we lengthen Shabbos?

Comment: I know it comes up on Chanukah about lighting menorah

Comment: Look at my answer for a treatment of all the issues brought up in your question and the comments.

Comment: Except for the Hanukah issue and why there might be a difference between Ner Hanukah and Megia on MS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ashkenazim and Sefardim do Havdalah after Mikrah Megilah as per [S.A. Rema 693 1 in the name of the Sefer Minhagim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14327&st=&pgnum=438), the reason being that we do whatever we can to push off leaving Shabbos. Since there is this consideration we do not look at which is *tadir*. The frequency of a *mitzvah* is only considered as a factor for precedence when all other things are equal.

However [Kaf HaHayim (Sefardi) does say in the name of Bigdei Yesha](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14425&st=&pgnum=340) that if he is reading Megila in his home, better to make Havdalah first so as to minimize the chance of him doing Melacha before Havdalah.

Comment: I ws wondering why today where people will drive back to Shul why they should not make Havdala at least if they know they will drive

Comment: That is a great question that should be asked as a stand alone!

Comment: Perhaps Eish, though, should be said before Megillah as you are benefiting from the light by reading the Megillah.