# On a "minor fast day" must one daven Maariv before eating once the fast is over?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, eating, maariv

Can a person eat once a fast is over and daven Maariv at a later time after eating? or is it a requirement to say Maariv prior to breaking one's fast?

Comment: Why would you think one must daven first? What does Maariv have to do with the fast?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6417/2091

Comment: Menachem, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2616

Comment: @DoubleAA What are you pointing out in that link?

Comment: @Ploni The Tashbetz in the Beit Yosef.

Answer (score 3):

According to [dinonline.org](http://dinonline.org/2017/09/25/maariv-on-a-fast-day/):

> You do not have to daven maariv before breaking the fast.